# Crystal Report View Fit to Screen Size

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

Hello I am using Web forms to view a crystal report design on Sap Crystal report. But when I am accessing the report its not displaying full to screen size. Even though I have used style width and  height to 100%  in div and form tag. Please recommend the right solution. Attaching the code and Screenshot of report Display.

[image: Report]

Here is the Code.

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // conn = Connections.database();
            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument report =
  new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
            report.Load(Server.MapPath("ContractReport.rpt"));

           
            CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = report;
        }
```

here is aspx file

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server"  style="height:100%; width:100%;>
<div  style="height:100%; width:100%;  overflow:auto">
    <table   style="height:100%; width:100%">

            <tr>

                <td>
                    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer2" 
          runat="server" AutoDataBind="true"  ToolPanelView="None"  
          BestFitPage="True" style="height:100%; width:100%;"   />

                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try to change that `<form id="form1" runat="server"  style="height:100%; width:100%;>`for that  `<form id="form1" runat="server"  style="height:100%; width:100%;">`?

Comment: yes i have tried that. problem not solved

Comment: Is there any `div` before `Form`? Or another `css` file on the page? Or this page is a daughter page that is receiving the formatting of a parent page, if this is it you must declare the elements with `ID` or `Class` for the page items. It would also be interesting to create the separate `css` file instead of declaring in each html item.

Comment: Can you post the full html code of the page in the screenshot (removing any private information)?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/I5lhnQP.png  ** here is the link for Complete html Code**